# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found when trying to add SQL features in Jitsi

Tags: eclipse, jdbc

I'm coding on Jitsi using Eclipse: I have to use JDBC to connect to MySQL database, so I've imported java.sql.* in my MainFrame class and I've included mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar into "Java Build Path" -> "Libraries".
    When I run the project, I've this error:

```
IOException in readRegistry: java.io.EOFException
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found by [76]
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(ModuleImpl.java:787)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl.access$400(ModuleImpl.java:71)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.ModuleImpl$ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleImpl.java:1768)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.gui.main.MainFrame.init(MainFrame.java:301)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.gui.main.MainFrame.<init>(MainFrame.java:239)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.gui.UIServiceImpl.loadApplicationGui(UIServiceImpl.java:133)
    at net.java.sip.communicator.impl.gui.GuiActivator.start(GuiActivator.java:129)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:629)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:1827)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1744)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1148)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I've created another project separated from Jitsi and I've tested my code following the same procedure (including java.sql.*; , adding the library), but the "new" project works fine and I can connect to my database, Jitsi doesn't.

Source:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLFirstTime {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
                String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cdcol"; 
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user", "pass");

                                // ...

                con.close();
        } catch(SQLException sqlEx) {
            System.out.println("Errore SQL");
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfEx) {
            System.out.println("Class NOT FOUND!");
            cnfEx.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

}
```

Thanks,
also if i'm using Ant to build the project how can I include the JDBC library?